# jquery parsing data and structure the html

Tags: jquery, json, parsing

I'm trying to parse this JSON and extract all the data from it. I'm not an expert on parsing it so would be nice if anyone could help?

http://jsfiddle.net/NJMyD/1044/

**html**

```
 <div class="items">
      <div class="item">
        <a href="#">
          <figure>
            <span><img src="" /></span>
            <figcaption>
              <h2 class="pod-title">
                <em data-title="Title of Show"></em>
              </h2>
              <p class="subtitle"></p>
            </figcaption>
          </figure>
        </a>
      </div>
    </div>
```

Comment: For starters, there are no `src` nor `url` properties anywhere on the object that you parse.

Comment: and you code is wrong at line 9.
You have to remove `var myData = JSON.parse(jsonString2);` and use the `data` object that is already parsed beacause of the JSON type return.

Comment: @psal thanks, as I said I'm not really an expert. How can I use the data?

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/NJMyD/1048/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, you have a lot of wrong things in your code (what should be in `str` ?, `src` and `url` don't exist in the JSON object, etc...).

Here is the modified script that return all of the `object.href` :

```
function getResults(str) {
   $.ajax({
    type: "GET",
    async: true,
    dataType: "jsonp",
    url: 'http://api.stb.search.sky.com/query.json?category=stb&term=andy+murray&sid=sport&adult=true&bouquet=4101&subbouquet=1&epgInfoBits=00020000&epgInfoBitsMask=001a0000&page=1&items=16&uid=4170198908',
    success: function(data){
    console.log(data);
     $.each(data, function() {
      $('.items').append(data.href+'<br />'); // <- do what you want here
     });
    }
   });
}
```

PS : you have to use JSONP datatype for cross-domain ajax query !

Comment: you juste have to call your function : 
add `getResults('');` at the end of your file.
btw, you can remove the `str` in you function declaration and call-it like that : `getResults();`

Comment: brilliant, thanks, why its all undefined? any way that I can get the right datas?

Comment: it's all undefined because the key simply doesn't exist in the JSON object ! look at [the page](http://api.stb.search.sky.com/query.json?category=stb&term=andy+murray&sid=sport&adult=true&bouquet=4101&subbouquet=1&epgInfoBits=00020000&epgInfoBitsMask=001a0000&page=1&items=16&uid=4170198908), there aren't any `src` and `url`.